Enlarging the length of a table cell
I must say that I am not familiar with tables in TeX and, indeed, have not yet understood how they work. I have tried to construct a table, the code is given below.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{7FFFD4}} p{3cm}}
\newcolumntype{d}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{FFC0CB}} p{4cm}}
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{DB5800}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |s|d|}
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Equazione differenziale lineare del primo ordine} \\
\hline
\qquad \quad $b=0$ & \qquad \qquad $b \neq 0$ \\
\hline
\textbf{omogenea}, \textbf{a variabili separabili} & \qquad \textbf{non omogenea}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}

In the output, however, I would like to enlarge the first cell of the table (the one in Aquamarine colour) so that the words 'omogenea, a variabili separabili' are in one line, and not broken up as in this case. Also, I would like to figure out a simple way to centre all the commands within the cells.

The easiest would probably be to replace p{3cm} by c, which will centre your content at a rubber width.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{7FFFD4}} c}
\newcolumntype{d}{>{\columncolor[HTML]{FFC0CB}} c}
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{DB5800}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |s|d|}
\hline
\rowcolor{lightgray} \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Equazione differenziale lineare del primo ordine} \\
\hline
$b=0$ & $b \neq 0$ \\
\hline
\textbf{omogenea}, \textbf{a variabili separabili} & \textbf{non omogenea}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}



Edit: Your [H] option to table requires the float package. However, I strongly discourage using this.

+1. You may also want to mention that the suggested setup offers no guarantee that the  width of the tabular environment won't exceed \textwidth, i.e., the width of the text block. That's not a problem for the tabular environment at hand, but it might be for other tables.

For information, here is a way to create that table with {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{DB5800}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \columncolor[HTML]{7FFFD4}{1}
  \columncolor[HTML]{FFC0CB}{2}
  \rowcolor{lightgray}{1}
\Body
\Block{1-2}{Equazione differenziale lineare del primo ordine} \\
$b=0$ & $b \neq 0$ \\
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
omogenea, a variabili separabili & non omogenea\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}



The width of the cell for p-type cells is the argument: p{3cm} means that cell will be 3cm wide. You can center it (instead of justified) either by changing p{3cm} to c or by using >{centering}p{6cm} or something similar.
If that does not answer your question, then there is something I am not understanding about what you want to do and/or what you expect.
By the way, your code as posted does not compile, but removing the [H] specifier fixes that.
